# Windows 8 Store App navigation with binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, navigation

My first C#/Xaml-experience was Windows Phone 8 where navigation worked like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Which meant that I could replace the String "/MyPage.xaml" by anything I needed and go to that page.

Is something similar possible with Windows Store Apps?

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage), UriKind.Relative);
```

MyPage isn't a string here so I can't simply replace it while the app is running. Still any way to do this?

What I am doing is:
I use a ListBox that gets it's data from a bound viewModel. There I wanted to store the target where the app should navigate to after a `SelectionChanged` Event is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like below if you get the string with namespace.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(Type.GetType("Namespace.PageName"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I looked for. Now it is completely dynamic binding. If I add a new Object in the ViewModel and a new class it will automatically create a button that leads to that view :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass the url of the page on selection changed and load the corresponding dataContext

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var title = NavigationContext.QueryString["title"];
    (DataContext as ImagePageViewModel).Load(title);
}
```

Follow this example which would fulfill your requirement

[page-navigation-in-windows-phone-and-windows-8](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/24/page-navigation-in-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx)

Comment: I thought about using this passed variable but I wanted to use this to implement the navigationBar of the app. This would mean that I'd put all classes/Views in 1 file and just select which will be showed when... it's not the nicest way to do this =/ Another way would be a class inbetween that takes this variable and decides where to go. But then I could create a switch-case in all views..